# PHPExcel как сформировать файл

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
    $xls = new PHPExcel();
        $xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();

$sheet->setTitle('Участники');
$sheet->setCellValue("A1", 'Категория участия');
$sheet->setCellValue("B1", 'Дата');
$sheet->setCellValue("C1", 'Имя');
$sheet->setCellValue("D1", 'email');
$sheet->setCellValue("E1", 'Телефон');
$sheet->setCellValue("F1", 'Группа');
$sheet->setCellValue("G1", 'Год выпуска');
$sheet->setCellValue("H1", 'Организация');
$sheet->setCellValue("I1", 'Коментарий');
foreach($strOut as $key => $user)
{
    $index = $key+2;
    $sheet->setCellValue("A".$index, $user->txt);
    $sheet->setCellValue("B".$index, $user->date);
    $sheet->setCellValue("C".$index, $user->name);
    $sheet->setCellValue("D".$index, $user->email);
    $sheet->setCellValueExplicit("E".$index, $user->phone, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
    $sheet->setCellValue("F".$index, $user->group);
    $sheet->setCellValue("G".$index, $user->year);
    $sheet->setCellValue("H".$index, $user->org);
    $sheet->setCellValue("I".$index, $user->comment);
    $sheet->getStyle('D'.$index)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
}
foreach(range('A','I') as $columnID)
    $sheet->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);



$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xls, 'Excel2017');
    $objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.csv', __FILE__));
    $objWriter->save('register.csv');
```

в чем может быть ошибка?данные не записываются

Comment: какие ошибки выводит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к PHPExel уже давно [не поддерживается](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet#phpexcel-vs-phpspreadsheet-), а на замену ему пришёл [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet), то логично использовать его.

> PhpSpreadsheet is the next version of PHPExcel. It breaks
>   compatibility to dramatically improve the code base quality
>   (namespaces, PSR compliance, use of latest PHP language features,
>   etc.).
>
> Because all efforts have shifted to PhpSpreadsheet, PHPExcel will no
>   longer be maintained. All contributions for PHPExcel, patches and new
>   features, should target PhpSpreadsheet develop branch.
>
> However PhpSpreadsheet is still unstable and not yet released. So if
>   you need stability stick to PHPExcel until this project is released.
>   If you prefer to live on the edge you can try to install this project
>   manually via composer, but there is no guarantee and it will likely
>   break again before an official release

Я не знаю, как вы подключаете библиотеку - это оставим на вас. Стоит также отметить, что имеется [масса примеров использования](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/tree/develop/samples), которые идут вместе с библиотекой и которые можно запустить локально.

Попробуйте записать хоть что-нибудь хотя бы в одну ячейку. Например, если ставить всё через composer и использовать IDE типа phpStorm, которая подхватывает все пути на лету, получится следующее

```
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');
    $format='xlsx';
    $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, $format);
    $writer->save('hello.'.$format);
```